# How to select a div with nth-child()?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have HTML structure like this:

```
<section id="main-content" class="photo-grid">
    <h2>Photos</h2>

    <div class="col-1-4">
            <a href="#">
                <p>File 503</p>
                <img src="#" />
            </a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-1-4">
            <a href="#">
                <p>File 508</p>
                <img src="#" />
            </a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-1-4">
            <a href="#">
                <p>File 505</p>
                <img src="#" />
            </a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-1-4">
            <a href="#">
                <p>File 525</p>
                <img src="#" />
            </a>
    </div>

    <br clear="all" />
</section>
```

I want to set different CSS properties to diferent .col-1-4 elements. How can I select them using :nth-child()?

I've tried `#main-content:nth-child(n)` and `.photo-grid:nth-child(n)`, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Side note, your HTML is invalid. `<a>` tags can't contain `<p>` tags.

Comment: Which ones are you trying to style different?

Comment: @j08691 I'm not sure if that is still true for HTML5 standard.

Comment: @user3008011 actually I need to apply different style rules to each of them. The real problem is that I have more than 4 divs to change, so it wouldn't be practical to add new classes or ids to each of them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `nth-of-type` and not `nth-child` for this, which is effectively the difference between saying '*select the nth child element of the specified element*' vs '*select the nth type of element which is a child of the specified element*':

`#main-content div:nth-of-type(1)`

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/4XPqX/)

Where `1` is the number (index starts from 1) of the `div` in question

You should apply `nth-of-type` to the specific type of element being targeted, you could even focus the above to:

`.col-1-4:nth-of-type(n)`

[**More on `nth-child` from MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-child)

> This can more clearly be described this way: the matching element is
>   the bth child of an element after all its children have been split
>   into groups of a elements each.

[**More on `nth-of-type` from MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-of-type)

> The :nth-of-type CSS pseudo-class matches an element that has an+b-1
>   siblings with the same element name before it in the document tree,
>   for a given positive or zero value for n, and has a parent element.
>   See :nth-child for a more thorough description of the syntax of its
>   argument. This is a more flexible and useful pseudo selector if you
>   want to ensure you're selecting the same type of tag no matter where
>   it is inside the parent element, or what other different tags appear
>   before it.

Answer (score 2):

This code `#main-content:nth-child(n) and .photo-grid:nth-child(n)` won't work because you are selecting nth-childs with id main-content or class photo-grid. You have to target the element inside that div which you want to use nth-child, for example:

```
#main-content div:nth-child(n) or .photo-grid div:nth-child(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use this also which is quite easy to do :

```
:nth-child(number)
{
css declarations;
}
```

Where n can be any number as per your requirements