# How can I get exactly one div while other divs has the same class, same child and the same parent? BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

As in the title, I am wondering how can i get specific div while there are many other divs in the same hierarchy with the same: parent, child and classname.

**Web scraper:** BeautifulSoup

Example:

```
<div class="main>
 <div class="parent">
  <div class="css-1wi2w6s enb64yk4"/>
 </div>
 <div class="parent">
  <div class="css-1wi2w6s enb64yk4"/>
 </div>
 <div class="parent">
  <div class="css-1wi2w6s enb64yk4"/> //div i want to get
 </div>
 <div class="parent">
  <div class="css-1wi2w6s enb64yk4"/>
 </div>
</div>
```

My goal is to get third child div from the top.

What i tried was:

```
rooms = doc.select_one('.css-1wi2w6s.enb64yk4 > div:nth-of-type(3)')
```

But it was returning an error.

The alternative solution:

```
def get_data(url):
    if url.startswith('link'):
        result = requests.get(url)
        doc = BeautifulSoup(result.text, 'html.parser')
        rooms = doc.find('div', {'class': 'css-1wi2w6s enb64yk4'}, string=True)
        z = rooms.find_next()
        x = z.find_next()
        c = x.find_next()
        v = c.find_next()
        b = v.find_next()
        n = b.find_next()
        m = n.find_next()
        l = m.find_next()
        k = l.find_next()
        j = k.find_next()
        h = j.find_next()
        for i in h:
            return i.string
    else:
        # rooms = doc.find_all('p', {'class':'css-b5m1rv er34gjf0'})
        # return rooms
        return "link"
```

After your comments:

```
htmld_doc = """
<div class="main">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="css-1wi2w6s enb64yk4">1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="css-1wi2w6s enb64yk4">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="css-1wi2w6s enb64yk4">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="css-1wi2w6s enb64yk4">4</div>
  </div>
</div>
"""
doc = BeautifulSoup(htmld_doc, 'html.parser')
rooms = doc.find('div', {'class': 'parent:nth-of-type(3) .css-1wi2w6s.enb64yk4'}, string=True)
print(rooms)
for i in rooms:
    print(i.string)
```

**TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select a div with nth-child()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23697364/how-to-select-a-div-with-nth-child)

Comment: Your attempt is looking for a child of `.css-1wi2w6s.enb64yk4` but the div you're looking for ***is*** of class `.css-1wi2w6s.enb64yk4`

Comment: No query will work as expected with invalid HTML, but were it valid `document.querySelector('.main div:nth-of-type(3) > .css-1wi2w6s.enb64yk4')` would return the element you indicated.

Comment: @pilchard ,not much. What i need is to how to convert it for BeautifulSoup beacouse i am passing the correct trace now and it still doesnt get it.

Comment: Does `doc.select('.css-1wi2w6s.enb64yk4')[2]` work?

Comment: @jqurious everytime ```doc.select('.css-1wi2w6s.enb64yk4')[6]``` is called, every time it returns different value, None/Random css/Sometimes it gives 3. ```doc.select('.css-1wi2w6s.enb64yk4')[6]``` works perfectly on example beacouse there is no dumb css etc. that it can throw